# My meteor project size is becoming out of control

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, nitrousio

I'm using an online IDE (nitrous) and my project size become 2.9 gb. I can't even run `meteor` command anymore.
Is there a way to clean the project to reset the size? (I can't run meteor reset)
Also, if I want to deploy the project on a server, will the project size become huge?
Note: It happened to me 2 times. I recreate another box then start uploading my project to it but recreating boxes and uploading is really painfull and waste of time.

Comment: Why is your project so large? My guess is that there are binary files that should be moved outside of the project itself. Unless you have a _lot_ of code :)

Comment: My code files size are about 88 kb and meteor folder is about 142 mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sup Rasof, look at this directory

```
root>projectName>.meteor>local>db>journal
```

Delete all Prealloac, i have the same issue, its some functionality from mongodb to preallocate date for you, i research some and looks like data is kinda ignored for meteor on the deploy, but like you are using nitrous.io you are actually using space of the box, so its not possible run the box.

Are you getting the "error: enospc, no space left on device"?

if its that just delete prealloc files

**Edit**

`Meteor Reset` also Works

Comment: I definitely wouldn't recommend deleting any files in the MongoDB data directory (unless you're hoping to corrupt or lose data!). I would instead try to understand where the space is being used and fix the problem properly.

Comment: if rasof like me, use nitrous just to test the app, its ok its just junk data, anyways like he say on command he wanna run meteor reset to so deleting prealloc its the same

Comment: if the intent is to completely reset the dbpath you should delete all of the files rather than selectively deleting files (which may result in a corrupt database). This still doesn't fix any underlying issue that leads to the storage growing over time, though. For example, preallocated files will be recreated as part of the default mongod behaviour. If disk space is a concern, options like [`smallfiles`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.smallFiles) will reduce storage allocation sizes for a test/dev deployment.

Comment: 'Meteor reset' doesn't work for me. But what you said before is solving my problem.

Comment: Sometimes Meteor reset works for me (thinking seriously on pay the $20 for the premium box)